# How sum up and print points of all exercises?

Tags: r-exams

I know that in `r-exam` I can assign points to exercises eg. via `expoints` in the exercise' meta-data. However, I don't know to get the sum of the points across all exercises.

As a specific usecase: Consider a test that (by formal university requirements) must consist of (say) 90 points. So, I need to track the number of points that are already included via the exercises of the test.

I'm unaware which variable tracks this score (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this information is not directly available, however it can be extracted from the metainformation contained in the output from any `exams2xyz()` interface. As a simple illustration consider:

```
library("exams")
set.seed(0)
exm <- exams2pdf(c("swisscapital.Rmd", "deriv.Rmd", "ttest.Rmd"),
  n = 1, points = c(1, 17, 2))
```

Now `exm` is a list with only n = 1 exam, consisting of three exercises, each of which provides its metainform (among other details). So you can extract the points of the second exercise in the first (and only) exam via:

```
exm[[1]][[2]]$metainfo$points
## [1] 17
```

So to get the points from all exercises in the first exam:

```
sapply(exm[[1]], function(y) y$metainfo$points)
## exercise1 exercise2 exercise3 
##         1        17         2
```

Of course, here it the `points` were explicitly set in `exams2pdf()` and were thus known. But the same approach can also be used if the points are set via the `expoints` tag in the individual exercises.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the great package!